# Node.js - anonymous function callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

This code works when the function passed to the getPage is a function statement, however, when I pass a function created on the fly, the param2 returns undefined? Why is this? Do I need to use call or bind?

```
function getPage(callback, param2) {

  var url = 'http://www.google.com';
  var param2 = param2;

  if (url) {
    url = url;
  } else {
    console.log('There was an error. No URL submitted');
  }

  callback(url, param2);
}


getPage(function(url, param2){
  console.log(`The URL of the page requested was ${url} and the added argument was ${param2}`);
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Post the code that doesn't work, and explain how exactly it fails and what you expected it to do instead.

Comment: Also, the code you posted is syntactically incorrect; the quotes are wrong in that `console.log()` call at the end.

Comment: Also note that `var param2 = param2`; in a function body where `param2` is a declared argument of the function is a misleading no-op.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please could you further explain? I'm still learning and don't fully understand what you mean... Thanks.

Comment: The function declares an argument called `param2`. So the `var` part of `var param2 = param2;` within the function doesn't do anything and is ignored. That leaves `param2 = param2;` which is, of course, a no-op. But looking at the code, you see `var` and it's easy to get misled into thinking that *isn't* a function argument.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I shall be sure to amend that and remember it for future purposes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just called getPage function without passing second parameter, so `param2` is undefined and callback is called with the same undefined `param2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the second argument like this:

```
getPage(function(url){...}, param2);
```